# Representable functor example

Tags: category-theory, representable-functor

Consider a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ which is enriched over $\mathrm{vect_k}$ (=finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$). $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian and semi simple. If it helps one can assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is rigid and has finitely many irreducble objects and irreducible unit object.

I want to show that the functor $$F_{D, V}: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathrm{vect_k}, C \mapsto V \otimes_k \mathrm{Hom}(C, D)$$ is representable.

On ordinary algebra basis I found that there is a connection between semi simple and projective and I think I heard something that a functor is representable if every object is projective.

But I guess that's only random, messy information clustered. Does anyone have more detailed information? A source to an article or book?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $V\simeq k^n$,$n$ finite so $FC \simeq \hom(C,D)^n \simeq \hom(C, D^n)$

Comment: but doesn't representable mean that $F$ is naturally isomorphic to a functor $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$? In your case it would be isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(-, A)$ with $A=D^n$.

Comment: That would be a covariant representable functor, here $F$ is clearly contravariant so it can't be isomorphic to $\hom(A,-)$. Representable usually means "$\hom(A,-)$ or $\hom(-,A)$, whichever makes sense"

Comment: ah yeah now I found it exactly the way you said it... Thanks a lot! thats a lot easier than I expected!